# generate multiple rows from its foreign key columns pointing to the same table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a data row with multiple fk pointing to the same table. How can I generate this:

table 1

```
 id | name | fk1 | fk2 | fk3
 1    test   EA    US    NULL
 2    test2  Null  UK    US
```

table 2

```
id | details
EA   East Asia
US   United States
UK   United Kingdom
```

I want to generate something like this

```
id | name | details
1    test   East Asia
1    test   United States
2    test2  United Kingdom
2    test2  United States
```

I've been looking around but probably I'm typing the wrong search keyword or phrase.

thanks

this is what I did

```
select t1.id,t1.name,t2.details from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.fk1
union
(select t1.id,t1.name,t2.details from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.fk2
)
union
select t1.id,t1.name,t2.details from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2 on t2.id = t1.fk3
```

but this table generates row with null

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: Also please show the queries you have tried even if they do not work

Comment: MSSQL.i forgot to add that tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `UNPIVOT` to get each of your fk columns as a separate row.

```
select u.id, u.name, t2.details
from table1 t1
unpivot(
    region for regions in (fk1, fk2, fk3)
) u
join table2 t2 on t2.id = u.region
```